# How can I inject an object into another namespace in python?

Tags: python, mocking, unit-testing

I'm writing some unittests for code written by someone else here at the office. Python is not my strongest language. While I've been successful with basic unit tests, mocking in python is throwing me for a loop.

What I need to do is override a call to ConfigObj and inject my own mock config/fixture into any ConfigObj call.

settings.py

```
from configobj import ConfigObj
config = ConfigObj('/etc/myapp/config')
```

utils.py

```
from settings import config
"""lots of stuff methods using various config values."""
```

What I would like to do is, in my unittests for utils.py, inject myself either for ANY call to ConfigObj or settings.py itself.

Many of the mocking libraries expect me to Mock my own classes but in the case of this app, it doesn't have any explicit classes.

Can it be done or are the python namespace restrictions too strict that I can't intervene in what a module that I'm importing imports itself?

Side note: running 2.7 so I can't do any of the tricks I've read about from 2.5.

Comment: Python 2.7 should be backwards-compatible to all Python 2.x versions. And in general, Python is a very dynamic language with little rules enforced by the implementation - I **bet** it is possible.

Comment: "...running 2.7 so I can't do tricks from 2.5."  Like what?  Not many things aren't incompatible between the two versions.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood but there were some tricks using __import__ that were taken out in 2.6? They might not even be applicable in this situation but I figured it was worth mentioning.

Even so, I'd like to be able do this with some standard mock library if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the tests are in a separate file from from `settings.py` and `utils.py` you can create a file `mock.py`

```
import configobj

class MockConfigObj(object):
     #mock whatever you wan

configobj.ConfigObj = MockConfigObj
```

and then `import mock` before importing (from) any module that itself imports `settings`. This will ensure that `settings.config` is created with `MockConfigObj`. If you want a uniform global mocking, import it before any file that imports `configobj`.

This works because python will store `configobj` in `sys.modules` and check that before actually reading from a file on subsequent imports. in `mock.py`, the identifier `ConfigObj` is just a reference to the entry in `sys.modules` so that any changes that you make will be globally visible.

This strikes me as a little hacky though but it's the best that I can think of.

Comment: Let me give this one a go. The key here is that I actually want to replace the ConfigObj with another ConfigObj of my own making. The namespace issues were what was throwing me off.

Comment: I think this one is going to work. I'm running into some errors with my mock object not being callable but I can see that when I do:

import mock
import utils

that it's calling my configobj instead which is what I wanted.

Comment: @lusis, if you provide more code samples, I can probably help if you haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: FYI, here's how I got it working. It still feels *ugly*:

http://gist.github.com/545953

I still don't feel any closer to groking mocking under python. It took me several iterations to get past random errors (not subscriptable and such) before I got something that worked.

I think the problem is the code I'm working with isn't object oriented. This really breaks a lot of the mock, mox, et. al. examples. 

I don't feel comfortable refactoring it until I have the unit tests in place to make sure I didn't actually break anything.

Answer (score 1):

Python namespaces are not strict at all within the same scope.  Just override the variable name containing your object (or the class itself and provided it) within the same scope you'd be expecting the original and that is good enough.

Now, whether or not what you're replacing it with behaves the same is up to you...

Comment: this will probably not work because `config` is already created using the real `ConfigObj` before `settings` is available to manipulate in the way you are describing. See my answer for the work around.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just overwrite the original function with another one?

There are no constants in Python, you can change everything, you could even do `True = False`.

Comment: ... or you can do `True, False = False, True`

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar situation before. Here is how I would go about addressing your problem.

Consider a test case for a function from `utils.py`.

```
import utils, unittest

class FooFunctionTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        utils._old_config = utils.config
        utils.config = MockClass()

    def tearDown(self):
        utils.config = utils._old_config
        del utils._old_config

    def test_foo_function_returns_correct_value(self):        
        self.assertEqual("success!", utils.foo())
```

Comment: but doesn't any initialization in `utils` occur using the `config` that is an instance of the real `ConfigObj`?

Comment: I'll give this one a shot but I don't think it will work because 'utils.py' bombs when settings.py can't load the config file (/etc/myapp/config).

Comment: @aaronasterling: Hmm. You are right. What do you think about patching `settings.py` instead? Or will it be impossible unless the source code of `settings.py` is changed to add a try/except around the init part?

Comment: on the other hand, it does avoid the potential problem of having to mock out `ConfigObj` for _every_ consumer that my method incurs.

Comment: I'm not sure how I feel about patching a module for the sake of unit testing. Also, I'm not sure what error would be `except` ed. As it stands, both of our answers have upsides and downsides.

Answer (score 0):

The following page is a good one on mocking and import

http://www.relaxdiego.com/2014/04/mocking-objects-in-python.html

Say you have a file named my_package1.py with the following code:

`class A(object):
          def init(self):`

and you then import that in my_package2.py with the code

`from my_package1 import A
     class A(object):
          def init(self):`

The first line of my_package2.py creates a variable under the my_package2 namespace called A. Now you have two variables my_package1.A and my_package2.A that both point to the same class in memory. If you want the code in my_package2.py to use a mocked up class A, then you will need to mock my_package2.A not my_package1.A